# Translation of "Je n’ai fait celle-ci plus longue"

Tags: sens, traduction, négation

A quote attributed to Blaise Pascal

> Je n’ai fait celle-ci plus longue que parce que je n’ai pas eu le
>   loisir de la faire plus courte.

is often translated

> I have made this longer than usual because I have not had time to make it shorter.

Why the *n'* before *ai* and why isn't that translated *I have not made this longer*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to see, but the negation is actually *ne ... que* meaning "only," so literally it means, "I made this one longer only because ..."

*Je **n'** ai fait celle-ci plus longue **que** parce que...*

Comment: I find questionable translations of this phrase many places, including the "literal" translation on WikiQuote.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you will use «**ne** ... **que** parce que» to answer a negative question. So your sentence must be the answer of a question (implicit or explicit) like :

> Pourquoi ne l'avez vous pas faite plus longue ?

It may imply you are asked to justify about what you did. You could also say :

> J'ai **uniquement** fait celle-ci plus longue **parce que**...

which means the same thing.

Adding some other sentences with the same structure :

> Je **ne** fais **que** passer
>   I am **only** passing through
>
> Il **ne** va au sport **que** pour se vider la tête
>   He **only** goes to sport in order to empty his mind
>
> Les cloches de l'église **ne** sonnent **que** le jour
>   Church's bells **only** ring during the daytime